# I am having problems centering a scroll div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a *div* that scrolls. I want it dead center on the page but it's not doing it with the code I provided below. Please help.

CSS

```
#content  
{
text-align: center;
}

.scroll
{
background-color:#fff;
color:#000;
width:500px;
height:400px;
overflow:scroll;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id ="content">
<div class="scroll"> Stuff </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A div is a block level element and will not listen to `text-algin`. You will either need to use `margin: 0 auto` on the `.scroll` element or make the div an inline-block element. Though support for block level elements to be inline-block level elements is not totally supported so you would have to use a span for complete support. However the better option is if your div has a set width, use a left and right margin of `auto` on the element you want to center.

Comment: "support for block level elements to be inline-block level elements is not totally supported" does any browser besides IE6 have such a problem?

Comment: No, I thought IE7 had it. I am really not sure. I usually just don't use a div if I NEED an inline-block element. I'm not sure why you would ever HAVE to use a div over a span.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align` only affects text. To position a `<div>` in the center, use
`margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto`.

Comment: Text align also affects inline/inline-block elements, not just text.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `display:inline;margin:auto` to your `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**HTML**

```
<div id ="content">
<div class="scroll"> Stuff </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content  
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.scroll
{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000;
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
}
```

live fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jNWva/)